# Undefined function conn/0 in View

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working through the Programming Phoenix 1.4 book, and while creating my view for Users, I ran into an issue. I continually get a compile error saying

```
== Compilation error in file lib/rumbl_web/views/user_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/rumbl_web/views/user_view.ex:3: undefined function conn/0
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:107: :elixir_locals."-ensure_no_undefined_local/3-lc$^0/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:107: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:208: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6`
```

when attempting to compile and run the project.
Here is the view in question:

```
defmodule RumblWeb.UserView do
  use RumblWeb, :view
  alias Rumbl.Accounts

  def first_name(%Accounts.User{name: name}) do
    name
    |> String.split(" ")
    |> Enum.at(0)
  end

  def username(%Accounts.User{username: username}) do
    username
  end

end
```

If I comment out the line `use RumblWeb, :view`, the project compiles (although it cannot render the view for obvious reasons). I am rather new to phoenix and elixir, so this has been pretty perplexing.

Comment: Can you please show the `RumbleWeb` mudule's `view/1` function please?

Comment: @JustinWood, There isn't a `view/1` function in rumbl_web.ex, it's a `view/0` function.

Comment: Right. Typo. Still want to see the function definition.

Comment: @JustinWood, I can't get that error by adding `conn` to the `view()` function (or anywhere else in the file).  The error will point to `rumbl_web.ex` but the op's error message says the error is in `user_view.ex`.  Can't hurt if the op posts the file--then I can compare it to mine.

Answer (score -1):

If I add `conn` to the third line of `views/user_view.ex`:

```
defmodule RumWeb.UserView do
  use RumWeb, :view
  conn  #====== *** HERE ***
  alias Rum.Accounts.User

  def first_name(%User{name: name} ) do
    name
    |> IO.inspect 
    |> String.split(" ")
    |> Enum.at(0)
  end


end
```

I get almost the same error as you:

```
$ mix phx.server
Compiling 9 files (.ex)
warning: variable "conn" does not exist and is being expanded to "conn()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/rum_web/views/user_view.ex:3


== Compilation error in file lib/rum_web/views/user_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/rum_web/views/user_view.ex:3: undefined function conn/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

I don't have the following in the middle of my error:

```
ensure_no_undefined_local/3-
```

but maybe that's due to differences in elixir versions.

If I put `conn` anywhere in `rumbl_web.ex`, then the error points to  `rumbl_web.ex`--not `user_view.ex`.  Are you posting all the output after you do `$ mix phx.server`?

Are you sure you don't have two windows open with two different versions of the file `user_view.ex`?  I would close all your editor's windows, then reopen your project and look at  `user_view.ex` again.

I had a weird error one time, and the solution was:

```
../rumbl$ rm -rf _build
```

then do:

```
../rumbl$ mix phx.server
```

and mix will rebuild your project, recreating the `_build` directory in the process.

Comment: This is a different stacktrace than what OP shows. Yours reports that it is in the eex file. OP's says it is in the view file.